# How to find emailID of user who visits URL received by user in mail

Tags: asp.net, .net

I am working on an asp.net project where user receives email from webserver.

User is given a url to visit.

Note: Obviously that url has a unqiue user identification pin

I want to know if this url is visited by same user who received mail or someone else. (In case someone tries to change unique pin and try access the web)

Is there anyway to achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't tell whether the visitor is the user or not. To the eyes of your application the one having the URL is the user. So if the PIN can be changed you'll have to encode a unique user identifier moreover the PIN in the URL sent for direct access.

You can also do some basic degree of fraud detection easily.
Using Request.UserHostAddress log the IP address of the first person clicking on the URL and collect his agent with Request.UserAgent
Then log each next visit in the same way.
If the second visit comes from the same IP and User-Agent then probably the user just revisited the email and clicked again.
Otherwise he probably forwarded the email to someone else or the email was stolen.
If you see lots of visits from different IPs and user agents then probably there has been a PIN sharing.